# Laravel 5 | Migration Alter-Change Column took so long

Tags: laravel, migration, alter

In my users table got millions of data.....

and I do this migration to change the default value on column `my_data`...

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('my_data')->default(0)->change();
});
```

I see in the `query_log.txt`, the `php artisan migrate` will execute this query

```
ALTER TABLE gn_users CHANGE my_data my_data VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL
```

which is very slow, almost 1 hour still the migration not done...

.

.

Then, i stop the migration, and i run raw query directly (i use `ALTER ... ALTER` instead of `ALTER ... CHANGE`)

```
ALTER TABLE gn_users ALTER my_data SET DEFAULT '0'
```

and this query done only in a seconds only...

.

.

so, my question is, how to make sure the Laravel run `ALTER ... ALTER` instead of `ALTER ... CHANGE` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the slowness occurs because the `CHANGE` command used by Laravel in SQL is mostly used for renaming columns, changing datatypes.

However `ALTER` column is more useful in this case as it is more appropriate for setting or changing default values.

(Source: https://hoelz.ro/ref/mysql-alter-table-alter-change-modify-column)

Probably Laravel is using change since it is the most appropriate for changes, can be universally used and is most widely used; searched through the docs and unfortunately couldn't find a specific way to force `ALTER` command instead of `CHANGE`.

To make sure that the correct command is ran and to force the correct command, you can always execute a raw query by using `DB` facade's methdod – `DB::statement("ALTER db ALTER col...")`

Better to always double check what commands builders will run and whether those commands will be efficient and valid for the case as they can't always predict the best way, your case is an excellent example.